# Kendo angular UI - date range picker

Tags: kendodaterangepicker

I want to show the start date and end date in a single text box using the Kendo angular date range control. I just went through the Telerik website. But no luck.

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grO7W.png)

I checked this page
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/daterange/.

But I don't get the design that I'm expecting, like in the attached image.

Can anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported, you can upvote and comment (if necessary) the following feature request:

https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1620460-show-date-range-in-a-single-input-field